Was the statement that Jesus ‘received sinners’ stated invidiously, meaning the people saying it could not consider themselves to be ‘sinners’?
Jesus is reported as mixing with sinners and eating with them in Luke 15:2. The RSV and KJV say this was “murmured”, which I take to show that those stating this fact were complaining, or – worse – sneering.
This question wants to explore
(1) how persons who knew themselves to be sinners would have felt, that: “This man receives sinners and eats with them”. Then,
(2) how might that contrast with what the people who murmured that fact thought of themselves with regard to sin.  Finally, For both groups,
(3) how would their view of salvation affect their response to what Jesus did?
I’m not looking for a hermeneutic-type answer because this question asks whether the unspoken implication that the murmurers had was a view of themselves that meant they did not view themselves as ‘sinners’. There are many Bible texts that deal with this matter of different views of what it is to be a sinner, not just the one I gave as an example. Nor do I want the parables Jesus gave after others said he ‘receives sinners and eats with them’ to be explored. The question is not about what Jesus said, but about what others said of him. Did they say it invidiously, with ill will, and being offended? If so, why?
I wanted to avoided the general tag of ‘sin’ and use ‘sinners’ and ‘sinless’, plus ‘salvation’, all of which are listed as possible tags.  Unfortunately, the sinner tag only gives, 'sinners-prayer' which is not what I'm after. It only gives 'sin' which is not the same as sinlessness. It only gives 'assurance of salvation', which is not what I'm after. The tags will turn out to be worse than useless if people just look at them and launch into that.
This is a topic about sinners compared with those who view themselves as sinless, and all with regard to salvation. I address this to those in the Reformed, Protestant, Evangelical category, noting that some may not identify themselves with any particular denomination, but be evangelical Protestants nevertheless.

In support of Mike Borden’s excellent answer, I post some relevant quotations from a Sunday evening sermon given by Charles Hadon Spurgeon on the evening of 14 September 1856 at the Exeter Hall, in the Strand, London.  The quotes are about sinners, sinlessness, and salvation. They are taken from a recently published booklet by New Park Street Pulpit, headed “An Appeal to Sinners”:
Regarding the Pharisees and scribes who murmured, “This man receives sinners and eats with them”, Baptist minister Spurgeon said:

They said of him what they intended for a disgrace, albeit it was highly to his honour, ‘This man receiveth sinners’. I believe that our Saviour could not have wished to have had a sentence uttered concerning him more evidently true or more thoroughly consistent with his sacred commission. It is the exact portrait of his character… Now the scribes and Pharisees wished to slander Christ, but in so doing they outstripped their intentions and bestowed upon him a title of renown: ‘This man receiveth sinners, and eateth with them.’ [page 2]


These scribes and Pharisees did virtually assert that they were not sinners. They marked out the publicans and the harlots and the worthless, and they said, ‘These are sinners; we are not.’ ‘Very well,’ said Christ, ‘I endorse the distinction you have made. In your own opinion, you are not sinners. Well, you shall stand exempt for the time from being called sinners – I endorse your distinction. But I beg to inform you that I came to save those very persons who, in their own estimation and in yours, are reckoned to be sinners.’


It is my belief that the doctrine of the text is this: that Christ receives not the self-righteous, not the good, not the whole-hearted, not those who dream that they do not need a Saviour, but the broken in spirit, the contrite in heart – those who are ready to confess that they have broken God’s laws and have merited his displeasure. These, and these alone, Christ came to save, and I reassert the subject of last Sabbath evening: that Jesus died for such, and for none other. [page 3]


Now, let us remark, beloved, that there is a very wise distinction on the part of God, that he hath been pleased thus to choose and call sinners to repentance, and not others. For this reason, none but these ever do come to him. There has never been such a miracle as a self-righteous man coming to Christ for mercy; none but those who want a Saviour ever did come. It stands to reason that, when men do not consider themselves in need of a Saviour, they never will approach his throne… no man can come to Christ until he truly knows himself to be a sinner. The self-righteous cannot come to Christ, for what is implied in coming to Christ? Repentance, trust in his mercy, and the denial of all confidence in one’s self. Now, a self-righteous man cannot repent and yet be self-righteous. He conceives that he has no sin; why, then, should he repent? [page 4]


It is only the man who knows his slavery by reason of the bondage of sin, and the man who knows himself to be sick even unto death by reason of the sense of guilt – it is only the man who feels he cannot save himself – who can with faith rely upon the Saviour. [page 5]


I dwell with special emphasis on this point, he receives none else. He will have none else to be saved but those who know themselves to be sinners. Full, free salvation is preached to every sinner in the universe, but I have no salvation to preach to those who will not acknowledge themselves to be sinners. To them I must preach the law, telling them that their righteousness is but filthy rags, that their goodness shall pass away as the spider’s web and shall be broken in pieces, even as the egg of the ostrich is broken in pieces, even as the egg of the ostrich is broken by the foot of the horse.  ‘This man receiveth sinners’, and receiveth none else.” [page 7]

In answer to your question: The Pharisees and scribes who murmured against Jesus because he ‘received sinners’ showed a “holier than thou” attitude. The inference was that they saw themselves as superior to the sinners with whom Jesus mixed. What they failed to realise was that salvation belongs only to those sinners who are humble enough to recognise that they are powerless to help themselves, and who turn to God in repentance, seeking forgiveness.
What they said was nasty, unpleasant and unfair. It was designed to cause dissent and show Jesus in a bad light. Instead, it exposed them and showed them for what they really were, hypocrites.

Did they say it invidiously, with ill will, and being offended?
While it can often be difficult to discern motivation when it is not clearly stated, as in "the Pharisees and Herodians asked Jesus, "Is it lawful to give tribute to Cæsar, or not?" in an attempt to trap him." I believe a fairly clear stance can be established regarding how certain ones considered themselves.  In attempting an answer I'd like to bring a few passages to bear.
First, note that it is the Scribes and Pharisees who are in view in the question at hand:

And the Pharisees and scribes murmured, saying, This man receiveth sinners, and eateth with them. - Luke 15:2

From John's Gospel we can see that this same group was unwilling to take action as an admission that they themselves were without sin:

And the scribes and Pharisees brought unto him a woman taken in adultery; and when they had set her in the midst, 
They say unto him, Master, this woman was taken in adultery, in the very act. Now Moses in the law commanded us, that such should be stoned: but what sayest thou? This they said, tempting him, that they might have to accuse him. But Jesus stooped down, and with his finger wrote on the ground, as though he heard them not. So when they continued asking him, he lifted up himself, and said unto them, He that is without sin among you, let him first cast a stone at her.  And again he stooped down, and wrote on the ground. And they which heard it, being convicted by their own conscience, went out one by one, beginning at the eldest, even unto the last: and Jesus was left alone, and the woman standing in the midst. - John 8:3-9

So even though folks in this group would not claim sinlessness (when pressed) we are told elsewhere that they did consider themselves righteous because of their religious activity and despise others:

And he spake this parable unto certain which trusted in themselves that they were righteous, and despised others: Two men went up into the temple to pray; the one a Pharisee, and the other a publican. The Pharisee stood and prayed thus with himself, God, I thank thee, that I am not as other men are, extortioners, unjust, adulterers, or even as this publican. I fast twice in the week, I give tithes of all that I possess. And the publican, standing afar off, would not lift up so much as his eyes unto heaven, but smote upon his breast, saying, God be merciful to me a sinner. - Luke 18:9-13

And not only righteous but, because of that self-assessed righteousness, they considered themselves to be better than others.  Perhaps it is this self-assessment that made them unable to perceive their need for repentance:

And Levi made him a great feast in his own house: and there was a great company of publicans and of others that sat down with them. But their scribes and Pharisees murmured against his disciples, saying, Why do ye eat and drink with publicans and sinners? And Jesus answering said unto them, They that are whole need not a physician; but they that are sick. I came not to call the righteous, but sinners to repentance. - Luke 5:29-32

Assessing themselves to be righteous they could not receive the call to repentance, which is the preparatory aspect of receiving Christ Jesus as Lord:

This is he, of whom it is written, Behold, I send my messenger before thy face, which shall prepare thy way before thee. For I say unto you, Among those that are born of women there is not a greater prophet than John the Baptist: but he that is least in the kingdom of God is greater than he. And all the people that heard him, and the publicans, justified God, being baptized with the baptism of John. But the Pharisees and lawyers rejected the counsel of God against themselves, being not baptized of him. - Luke 7:27-30

From these verses, among quite a few others, it can be understood that;

there were certain individuals who, because of their religious activity and theological knowledge, considered themselves as righteous in themselves.
These folks, due to their assessment of others in comparison to their self-assessment, considered themselves as better than others.
While they would not state categorically that they were without sin, they would often disparagingly refer to others as sinner.
They despised others who were not righteous in the same manner as themselves.

Therefore, it is safe to conclude that there were in Jesus' day (and I suggest still are today) people who, trusting in their theological knowledge and their religious activity, self-assess as righteous, which enables the assessment of others as less righteous, which engenders invidious disdain of those deemed to be sinners, which stands in the way of true repentance thereby making the true Gospel an offense to their self-assessment.
Thus it is that those relying on their knowledge and participation in religious activity for their righteousness will call for sinners to join their ranks and pursue righteousness their way rather than rejoice that such a one repents and finds life in Christ alone.  Ill will indeed.
